# How can I configure autoadjustment for grid row 0?

Tags: winui-3, winui

I have two infobars as part of grid row 0 which are only open in some cases. How can I configure the code below that the row 0 auto adjusts it's high depending on whats inside? It should shrink when the infobars are closed and stretch when it's opened.

```
<Grid Margin="{StaticResource NavigationViewPageContentMargin}" CornerRadius="8">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorLight3}" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="3" >
            ........
        </StackPanel>
        <InfoBar IsOpen="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorA}" Foreground="red" IsIconVisible="True" IsClosable="True" Title="Issue Detected" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorAContent}" Margin="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorAMargin}"/>
        <InfoBar IsOpen="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorB}" Foreground="red" IsIconVisible="True" IsClosable="True" Title="Issue Detected" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorBContent}" Margin="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorBMargin}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="NavigationFrame" Grid.Row="2" Background="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorLight3}" Padding="3" CornerRadius="8"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried some playaround with the RowDefinition high, but did not find the solution. Could it be that some properties inside the inner stackpanel prevent the auto adjustment?

Comment: I created a sample app using your code but the ``StackPanel Grid.Row="0"`` does shrink when you close one or both ``InfoBar``s. But of course does not goes to Height 0 because of the ``StackPanel`` inside of it. You can easily see it by setting the ``BorderBrush`` and ``BorderThickness`` to ``StackPanel Grid.Row="0"``. Can you give more explanation about your question?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found out that it works with xBind .. Mode=TwoWay for the binded properties in the infobars. Don't really understand why.

Comment: Might be because ``x:Bind``'s ``Mode`` is ``Oneime`` by default. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#:~:text=%7Bx%3ABind%7D%20has,part%20of%20the%20binding.).